Does it make sense to use Batch Normalization in autoencoders for image reconstruction?
I’m working on an autoencoder for image reconstruction, and I would like to hear your opinions on using Batch Normalization (BN) in this type of architecture.

What are the advantages of applying BN in the encoder and decoder layers of an autoencoder focused on image reconstruction?
In terms of performance and reconstruction quality, can Batch Normalization negatively affect the results, especially in tasks that require high precision in the final output? I’ve read that, in some cases, normalization could lead to a loss of critical information during reconstruction, as the activations are modified and could alter the features of the original images.
Are there specific cases or configurations where you would recommend its use or avoidance?

Thank you in advance for any advice or experiences you can share on this topic.
